# Is there a way to dump the adt compile command line from Flash Builder 4.7

Tags: air, flash-builder

Flash Builder 4.7 has very nice setting dialogues for AIR compilation.

Is there a way to dump/display the full command line Flash Builder using when it compiling ipa file?

The reason why I’m asking for this, is because, it is very frustrating when hand code adt compilation command line for a project with a good number of assets, as well as a couple of ANEs.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Flash Builder uses Java to trigger the adt.jar file to compile a project. You have to get the parameters of the Java executable process in order to find the command being executed.

You can do this on Windows through the ProcessExplorer tool. Just select the java.exe process and inspect its properties. There's a command-line text field in one of the properties tab.

It's a little more complicated on OS X. First, use the Activity Monitor to get the process ID of the java executable. Launch a new terminal window and type the following statement

```
ps -p PROCESS_ID | open -tf
```

Replace PROCESS_ID with the actual number from Activity Monitor. The result will be displayed in a new TextEdit window.

Note that there may be multiple instances of the Java executable. Just select the first one launched, i.e. the one with the lowest process ID among all the instances of java.